ASP.NET Core Web API Identity extension
I have an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API. I don't have an account controller to handle the Identity endpoints, I just added app.MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>(); in Program.cs. This method worked fine until I had to modify some of the register logic.
I didn't know how to extend it and I simply copied the whole Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.IdentityApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions and added it in my Extensions folder.
Of course, I renamed it to be used like this: app.MapCustomIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();.
Is this an OK way to handle this kind of situation? Please, advise.
Thanks!

Hi @Boyan Royachki, It is a quick solution for coppying and modifying the source code, it's advisable to consider more maintainable and scalable approaches, such as customizing services, creating custom endpoints, or adding custom controllers.
